# update value when key is found in dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary, sequence, biopython

```
tiny_reads = [
Sequence('CGTGCAA'),
Sequence('TGCAATG'),
Sequence('ATGGCGT'),
Sequence('GGCGTGC'),
Sequence('CAATGGC'),]



dictionary = {} 

def kmers(reads, k):
for line in tiny_reads:
    for kmer in line.iter_kmers(k, overlap=3):
        dictionary[str(kmer)] = 1
        print(dictionary)
        if str(kmer) not in dictionary: 
            dictionary[str(kmer)] = 1
        else:
            dictionary[str(kmer)] += 1


 #print(dict)
 kmers(tiny_reads, 3)
 print(dictionary)
```

My code go through sequences above and uses iter_kmer() to break the sequence into small reads of size 3 ('CGT'). I want to create a dictionary that will have all these small reads and the count of how many they are in the sequence. The result im getting is off and im not sure why.

Expected result:

kmers(tiny_reads, 3)
{'AAT': 2,'ATG': 3, ...'TGG': 2}

My result:
{'CAA': 2, 'GTG': 2, 'GCA': 2, 'GCG': 2, 'ATG': 2, 'TGC': 2, 'CGT': 2, 'AAT': 2, 'GGC': 2, 'TGG': 2}

My result is incorrect because 'ATG' is repeated 3 times. Can you guys help please this frustrating me.

Answer (score 3):

You are resetting the counter in the dictionary with every line that you are iterating through:

With the code you already have, I would use a defaultdict.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def kmers(reads, k):
    dictionary = defaultdict(int)
    for line in tiny_reads:
        for kmer in line.iter_kmers(k, overlap=3):
            dictionary[str(kmer)] += 1
```

If I were writing the code I would probably concatenate all the lines together and then use Counter.

```
def kmers(reads, k):
    accumlator = []
    for line in tiny_reads:
        accumlator += line.iter_kmers(k, overlap=3):
    dictionary = Counter(accumlator)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly how iter_kmers works, but perhaps you are looking for something like the following?

```
tiny_reads = [
    Sequence('CGTGCAA'),
    Sequence('TGCAATG'),
    Sequence('ATGGCGT'),
    Sequence('GGCGTGC'),
    Sequence('CAATGGC')
]

kmer_d = dict()

def kmers(reads, k):
    for tiny_r in tiny_reads:
        for kmer in tiny_r.iter_kmers(k, overlap=3):
            d = kmer_d.get(str(kmer), 0)
            kmer_d[str(kmer)] = d + 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
     kmers(tiny_reads, 3)
     print(kmer_d)
```

Bear in mind that this is not the fastest implementation probably, however it simply fixes the error with the minimal change. 
When reading values from a dictionary, using the .get() method you can set a default value in case no entry is found